# Query Most Recent Records in MS Access Based on Date Provided in Form Field

Tags: database, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

Let me start by noting I have spent a few days searching through S.O. and have not been able to find a solution. I apologize in advance if the solution is very simple, but I am still learning and appreciate any help I can get.

I have a MS Access 2010 Database, and I am trying to create a set of queries to inform other forms and queries. There are two tables: Borrower Contact Info (BC_Info) and Basic Financial Indicators (BF_Indicators). Each month, I review and track key performance metrics of each borrower. I would like to create a query that supplies the most recent record based on a textbox input (Forms![Portfolio_Review Menu]!Text47).

Two considerations have separated this from other posts I have seen in the 'greatest-n-per-group' tag:

> 1. Not every borrower will have data for every month.
> 2. I need to be able to see back in time, i.e. if it is January 1, 2019 and I want to see the metrics as of July 31, 2017, I want to make
>      sure I am only seeing data from before July 31, 2017 but as close to
>      this date as possible.

Fields are as follows:

> BC_Info
>   - BorrowerName
>   -PartnerID
>
> BF_Indicators
>   -Fin_ID
>   -DateUpdated

The tables are connected by BorrowerName -- which is a unique naming convention used for the primary key of BC_Info.

What I currently have is:

```
SELECT BCI.BorrowerName, BCI.PartnerID, BFI.Fin_ID, BFI.DateUpdated
FROM ((BC_Info AS BCI
    INNER JOIN  BF_Indicators AS BFI
        ON BFI.BorrowerName = BCI.BorrowerName)
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Fin_ID, MAX(DateUpdated) AS MAX_DATE
        FROM BF_Indicators
        WHERE (DateUpdated <= Forms![Portfolio_Review Menu]!Text47 OR
        Forms![Portfolio_Review Menu]!Text47 IS NULL)
        GROUP BY Fin_ID
    ) AS Last_BF ON BFI.Fin_ID = Last_BF.Fin_ID AND
        BFI.DateUpdated = Last_BF.MAX_DATE);
```

This gives me the fields I need, and will keep records out that are past the date given in the textbox, but will give all records from before the textbox input -- not just the most recent.

Results (Date Entered is 12/31/2018; MEHN-45543 is only Borrower with information later than 09/30/2018):

```
BorrowerName    PartnerID   Fin_ID  DateUpdated 
 MEHN-45543         19         9    12/31/2018 
 ARYS-7940           5        10     9/30/2018 
 FINS-21032         12        11     9/30/2018
 ELET-00934          9        12     9/30/2018
 MEHN-45543         19        18     9/30/2018
```

Expected Results (Date Entered is 12/31/2018; MEHN-45543 is only Borrower with information later than 09/30/2018):

```
BorrowerName    PartnerID   Fin_ID  DateUpdated 
 MEHN-45543         19         9    12/31/2018 
 ARYS-7940           5        10     9/30/2018 
 FINS-21032         12        11     9/30/2018
 ELET-00934          9        12     9/30/2018
```

As mentioned, I am planning to use the results of this Query to generate further queries that use aggregated information from the Financial Indicators to determine portfolio quality at the time.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. And again, thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide sample raw dataset as text in post, not image. Is there a unique identifier field such as autonumber?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion June7. I have added sample data -- is this what you meant or would something else be more helpful? PartnerID is a unique identifier in the BC_Info table and Fin_ID is a unique identifier in BF_Indicators. Both are autonumbers.

Comment: You still show example results, not example raw source data. But think I got tables figured out anyway.

Comment: Why aren't you using PartnerID as PK/FK instead of BorrowerName?

Comment: Thank you June7, these seem to work. I will continue to experiment with each as I build more queries off these. As for the PK/FK being the BorrowerName, I had gotten confused and thought the PK needed to be able to connect to other tables. There isn't a sound reason for using the BorrowerName, but it is a unique field so I assumed there was no harm in continuing to use it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It will work but stores more data as FK and text values index slower.

Comment: Good point. I will change it around -- probably easier to do now than after months of data entry, I assume. Thanks for the insight, and thanks again for answering the original question in such detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining BC_Info to a query that aggregates BF_Indicators on BorrowerName, not Fin_ID. Tested with literal date value:

```
SELECT BC_Info.*, MaxDate 
FROM BC_Info 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT BorrowerName, Max(DateUpdated) AS MaxDate 
 FROM BF_Indicators WHERE DateUpdated <=#12/31/2018# GROUP BY BorrowerName) AS Q1 
ON BC_Info.BorrowerName=Q1.BorrowerName;
```

If you need to include Fin_ID in the results, then:

```
SELECT BC_Info.*, Fin_ID, DateUpdated FROM BC_Info 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM BF_Indicators WHERE Fin_ID IN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Fin_ID FROM BF_Indicators AS Dupe 
     WHERE Dupe.BorrowerName=BF_Indicators.BorrowerName AND DateUpdated<=#12/31/2018# 
     ORDER BY Dupe.DateUpdated DESC)
) AS Q1
ON BC_Info.BorrowerName = Q1.BorrowerName;
```

If you don't like TOP N, adjust your original query:

```
SELECT BCI.BorrowerName, BCI.PartnerID, BFI.Fin_ID, BFI.DateUpdated
FROM ((BC_Info AS BCI
    INNER JOIN  BF_Indicators AS BFI
        ON BFI.BorrowerName = BCI.BorrowerName)
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT BorrowerName, MAX(DateUpdated) AS MAX_DATE
        FROM BF_Indicators
        WHERE (DateUpdated <= #12/31/2018#)
        GROUP BY BorrowerName
    ) AS Last_BF ON BFI.BorrowerName = Last_BF.BorrowerName AND
        BFI.DateUpdated = Last_BF.MAX_DATE);
```

And 1 more to think about:

```
SELECT BC_Info.PartnerID, BC_Info.BorrowerName, BF_Indicators.Fin_ID, BF_Indicators.DateUpdated
FROM BC_Info RIGHT JOIN BF_Indicators ON BC_Info.BorrowerName = BF_Indicators.BorrowerName
WHERE (((BF_Indicators.DateUpdated)=DMax("DateUpdated","BF_Indicators","BorrowerName='" & [BC_Info].[BorrowerName] & "' AND DateUpdated<=#12/31/2018#")));
```